# Weighted space with two weight functions

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

By a weighted real function space, one means a set of the form
$$C_w(\mathbb{R})=\{f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}:\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)w(x)|<\infty \} $$
with the supremum norm
$$\|f\|=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)w(x)|<\infty .$$
In a [previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2527783/62839), I was told that $C_w(\mathbb{R})$ is complete if $w$ is bounded below by some positive constant.

My question is: what if I'm interested in estimating the suprema of $f$ multiplied by two weight functions simultaneously? Are spaces of the form
$$C_{w_1,w_2}(\mathbb{R})=\{f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}:\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)w_1(x)|,\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)w_2(x)|<\infty \}$$
and
$$\{f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}:\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)w_1(x)| \leq M_1,\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)w_2(x)| \leq M_2 \} $$

well documented in the literature? Are they Banach? What is the norm if so?

Reading up on the subject led me to [Interpolation spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space), but I don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
C_{w_1,w_2}=C_{w_1}\cap C_{w_2}.
$$
$C_{w_1,w_2}$ is the intersection of two Banach spaces, and is itself a Banach space with the norm
$$
\|f\|_{w_1,w_2}=\max\bigl(\|f\|_{w_1},\|f\|_{w_2}\bigr).
$$